# Can’t generate signed apk in android studio

Tags: android

Dears;

I can build normal APK for my project , But I can’t build signed APK , the bellow error Appears;

```
AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #4: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MgeLast\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png', attempting to stop daemon
```

I’ve tried to change the launcher icon but still the same problem

and suggestion ?

Comment: check if you have any resource in debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in 3.2 and 3.3
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/117486770#comment17

add to your app gradle:

aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

This allows build to go past this error.

Comment: Thanks , It solved but after adding firebase the issue happened again with the following error :AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d9faaaf26fc140f365e3b207d6db990b\jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon

Comment: It was because of version a rollback to 4.0.2 and it works normally : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
Hope that they will correct it

Answer (score 0):

If you have that drawable file in `Drawable` folder then I think its a cache issue.Go to `File->Invalidate Cache & Restart`. It will restart the android studio. try to build now.